# How to insert ' into postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

Here i want insert a name into pg.
Sometimes,this name is not regular like the following picture.
http://ob9j09f06.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-11-09-22%3A58%3A19.jpg

How can i update this data into db?

Comment: Try escaping the `'` character, such as `'Afanas\'ev ...`

Comment: By not using string manipulation and using query parameters instead.

Comment: If you have this bug, you'll have a bunch of other security-impacting ones as well. If you only work around the immediate symptom instead of fixing the practices that caused it, then you're... well... only fixing the symptom. Always, always, always keep code and data out-of-band from each other, and remember [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: For future reference, here is a complete list of times it is appropriate to use string formatting operations to construct a SQL command:.

Comment: BTW, in general -- please don't use images of text in your questions. They can't be searched, they can't be copy-and-pasted, they're opaque to accessibility tooling such as screen readers, they're ugly to people on higher-resolution displays, and the links can break over time, reducing the value of the StackOverflow knowledgebase as it ages. Instead, copy-and-paste the actual text, formatting it as a code block (with `<!-- language: none -->` to turn off syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use query parameters.
In Sqlite you would do something like:

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO articles VALUES(?, ?)'
to_db = [authors, link]
curs.execute(sql_insert, to_db)
```

or to update:

```
sql_update = 'UPDATE articles SET authors = ? WHERE link = ?'
to_db = [authors, link]
curs.execute(sql_update, to_db)
```

to_db is a list of parameter that you pass, instead of using string manipulation through %s as comment of @Colonel Thirty Two suggested.

Comment: With the psycopg2 DB-API module (which the OP is using), paramstyle is `pyformat`, so instead of `?` it's a `%s` as the placeholders -- but still passing the arguments out-of-band rather than substituting them.

Comment: [The relevant documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) is worth linking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.